# Unnable to connect to localhost via smtp

Tags: localhost

I was trying to learn the PHP mail function and for that i configured Mercurymail in xampp.It was working fine for some time..But after an hr or so my mail client Thunderbird showed an error "could not connect to localhost:connection refused"..

But again after some time it started working fine...

Is there any problem with ports....

POP:110(Incoming)
SMTP:25(outgoiong)

or any firewell issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the windows firewall temporarily, or add exceptions for port 25, then retry. You can also telnet to localhost port 25 and see what happens for more verbose output. If it times out or refuses connection then it is likely a firewall issue.

Comment: tried adding exception...not working.telnet localhost 25 returned could not open connection to the host connection failed... also both port 25 and 110 are free..

Comment: Then your software is not configured correctly.